# Is there any way to print custom error message when kubernetes pre-install job fails?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-jobs

I have a helm chart and the helm chart is only installed when the pre-install hooks is succeeded.
When the job fails, the error is

Error: failed pre-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded

Is there any way i can print my custom message that pops up so that i do not have to go inside the job to find the cause of failed helm chart installation?

Comment: There is no way to show a custom messages using HELM, but you can put the message in your job container, so if it fails, then will show you in the container logs. Is it work for you?

Comment: I already have logs in my container. Thanks, i was just curious if we could have custom message when the job fails

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comments:

There is no way to print custom messages in HELM.
A strategy that could be used is send the application logs to stdout and them verify them with `kubectl logs` command.

Answer (score 0):

you can use {{- fail "failed pre-install: job failed: BackoffLimitExceeded" -}}